# Get handle to nested array object using js

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I get a handle to "[[PromiseValue]]"?

I tried "a[[PromiseValue]]"

[image]

Comment: You want to have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916710/what-does-promisevalue-mean-in-javascript-console-and-how-to-do-i-get-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with arrays. `[[PromiseValue]]` is the name of the property.

It's an *internal property* of the promise object you shouldn't access directly (if you even can, which I doubt). If you could, it would be with brackets notation and a string:

```
a["[[PromiseValue]]"]
```

...but again, you shouldn't do that (<s>if you even can</s> I checked, and you can't). Instead, use `then` to get notification when the promise has been settled, and to receive its value:

```
a.then(function(value) {
    // ...
});
```

Example:

```js
var a = new Promise(function(resolve) {
  resolve("Hi"); // <== Settles the promise and sets its value
});
a.then(function(value) {
  snippet.log(value); // Using the value
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```