# return value from Promise

Tags: meteor, promise, synchronization, return

Considering the example:

```
function returnValue () {
   return somePromise.then (
     function (someThing) {
       return {
         sucess: true,
         data: someThing
       }
     },
     function (someError) {
       return {
         sucess: false,
         data: someError
       }
     }
   )
}

Console.log (returnValue ())
```

What should I do so that I actually have "someThing" or "someError"? And not a Promise pending?

Just to note ... when I write a code like this within "Meteor.methods" it works exactly as I would like, that is, it returns a value that I return to the client, but outside of "Meteor.methods" or in the client (browser, using or not any framework) the one I have is a Promise pending.

Answer (score 0):

The function passed to `.then()` returns results asynchronously. The `Promise` `value` of the fulfilled `Promise` will be available as the argument of the passed function. `Console.log (returnValue ())`, as you noted, logs the `Promise` itself, not the `Promise` `value`. Chain `.then()` to `returnValue()` call. Also, `Console.log (returnValue ())` should be `console.log()`.

```js
let somePromise = Promise.resolve("abc");

function returnValue () {
   return somePromise.then (
     function (someThing) {
       return {
         sucess: true,
         data: someThing
       }
     },
     function (someError) {
       return {
         sucess: false,
         data: someError
       }
     }
   )
}

returnValue().then(function(result) {
  console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: Right, but does not that take the value out of the promise, or should I accept that this is impossible from the browser?

Comment: @rogeriojlle Hesitant to state what is "impossible". Would suggest reading the specification [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) _"A promise represents the eventual result of an asynchronous operation. The primary way of interacting with a promise is through its `then` method, which registers callbacks to receive either a promise’s eventual value or the reason why the promise cannot be fulfilled."_ See also [Promises](https://www.promisejs.org/), [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970#youre-missing-the-point-of-promises).

Comment: @rogeriojlle See [What does \[\[PromiseValue\]\] mean in javascript console and how to do I get it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916710/what-does-promisevalue-mean-in-javascript-console-and-how-to-do-i-get-it)