# how to get a array for a promise

Tags: reactjs

[image]

now I get a promise object,but I don't know to get the PromiseValue from that promise.
The structure is following that

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
        [[PromiseValue]]:Array(63)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \[\[PromiseValue\]\] mean in javascript console and how to do I get it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916710/what-does-promisevalue-mean-in-javascript-console-and-how-to-do-i-get-it)

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

`Promise.all([array where each element is a Promise])`

`Promise.all` returns a single promise. Depending on the implementation, the response is an array containing the response from each Promise in sequence. If any of the Promise rejects, `Promise.all` rejects with the rejected value.

Comment: I need the result as the style of array or object ,rather than return promise object

Comment: how about using `.then` and `.catch` as so `Promise.then(function(your_wanted_value_is_here) {} ).catch()`