# React form onSubmit event object missing values on devtools

Tags: reactjs

I have a form in react:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
```

And the handleSubmit function is:

```
  handleSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
    console.log(values.target[0].value);
    values.preventDefault();
  }
```

`values.target[0].value` prints the correct value of the input. However, in chrome devtools I don't see it. I see instead `[[Target]]`.

What does the `[[]]` mean, and where is the `target[0].value`?

[image]

Comment: The origin of the stuff inside `[[ ]]` is explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28917161/368697

Answer (score 4):

React uses something called `SyntheticEvent` which is a Proxy to original browser event. It does that to make your code behave consistently across browsers.

[From React docs:](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

> Your event handlers will be passed instances of SyntheticEvent, a
>   cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event. It has the
>   same interface as the browser’s native event, including
>   stopPropagation() and preventDefault(), except the events work
>   identically across all browsers.

So in your code you are passed SyntheticEvent:

```
handleSubmit = (syntheticEvent) => {
  console.log(syntheticEvent);
  console.log(syntheticEvent.target[0].value);
  syntheticEvent.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: So what does the [[Target]] in the devtools mean?

Comment: @DM It means that it is an internal property. See [this answer for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28917161/4443323).