# Where is the spefic location of id variable in window/global object when we use an element with IDs?

Tags: javascript, html

Yes, we already know the id becomes the global variable. But where is the location of this variable as a key in window object?

**How you explain we cannot find the variable as a key in window object?** I have been so curious about it all the time. Thank you very much.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <a id="a"></a>
  </body>
  <script>
    console.log(window.__proto__.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('a')) 
    // true
    // a is a key in window.__proto__.__proto__

    console.log(Reflect.ownKeys(window.__proto__.__proto__)) 
    // [Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)]
    // but window.__proto__.__proto__ only has one key: Symbol.toStringTag, there is no key named "a"
  </script>
</html>
```

Like the example I just listed, we can use `a` or `window.a` in javascript, but it looks like `a` is not a key in window object. It is so wired.

Comment: I suspect the `WindowProperties` class implements this dynamically.

Comment: @traktor Isn't this then just a dupe of [Do DOM tree elements with IDs become global properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278)

Comment: Hi, @traktor. Thank you, it is not a dupe. As I clarified in the question: "we already know the id becomes the global variable.". But I am asking where is the specific location of the id in window object and it is not answered in that post. Thank you :)

Comment: OK, back to reopening the question. As yet I have found no empirical clue about where the  window "properties" created for DOM elements with ids are held. They are not own properties, they are not inherited properties since they are not returned using `for...in..`, and can be globally redeclared using `const` and `let`.  @gre_gor I've deleted earlier comments to tidy up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These "global variables" are specified as [*named properties* on the `window` object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#named-access-on-the-window-object). Such [named properties](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-support-named-properties) are defined in WebIDL, as is their representation in an ECMAScript runtime. It specifies that [named properties of a `[Global]` object](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#Global) must "*be exposed on an object in the prototype chain – the [named properties object](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-named-properties-object) – rather than on the object itself*". And for that [named properties object](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#named-properties-object), it specifies an exotic object with various custom [internal methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28916710/1048572). (To implement this yourself, you'd use a  `Proxy`.) However, it does not specify a custom *[[OwnPropertyKeys]]* method, making the named properties not enumerable:

> Note: The [[OwnPropertyKeys]] internal method of a named properties
> object continues to use [OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys),
> unlike the counterpart for [legacy platform objects](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-legacy-platform-object).
> Since named properties are not “real” own properties,
> they will not be returned by this internal method.

This explains the discrepancy between `hasOwnProperty` and `ownKeys` that you observed.

Comment: your explanation is deep and clear and just opened my mind. Thank you so much!!!@Bergi

Comment: Hi @Bergi I have a question regarding this. If `OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys` is used as the object doesn’t have its own `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` method, then shouldn’t the default behaviour of `OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys` be used, which as far as I can tell should iterate keys which are enumerable and non-enumerable? So if it iterates all properties then shouldn’t the “named properties” be included in the returned result?

Comment: @NickParsons `OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys` does that, but the *named properties object* simply is an empty object. It has no [properties](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-object-type) stored on it. (This storage of property descriptors is still described only by prose in the spec, not via an internal slot…)

Comment: Curiously this explains why if you shadow a named element, by creating an ordinary window property using the element's `id` as property name, deleting the window property restores global access to the element rather than returning `undefined`. @Bergi Thanks for the great answer!